# I want to post my research on triangular numbers, but where?

Tags: research, publishing

I've been looking for a long time to see if I could post my results anywhere, my issue is that I'm only 16 and don't think it's appropriate for me to write to a journal. Also I don't know if what I have found out is actually relevant (although I think it's interesting) or has been published and found out before. I could just write it into any forum but wouldn't that mean that anyone could copy my research and display it as his work? Thanks for helping me with this problem.

Comment: If you write about it here, it's on the public record and easily found in a search.  That makes it much less easy for someone to steal it and publish it as their own than if you published it in some obscure print journal that nobody reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permit me to draw attention to the journal,
[Involve—A Journal of Mathematics](http://pjm.math.berkeley.edu/involve/about/cover/cover.html). Snippets from *About the Journal*:

> "*Involve* is dedicated to showcasing and encouraging high quality mathematical research involving students (at all levels). ... Submissions in all mathematical areas are encouraged. However, each manuscript should include a minimum of 1/3 student authorship. ...
>   Involve is a publication in between the extremes of purely undergraduate research journals, which in general are aimed at undergraduate audiences, and mainstream research journals."

There's also the Canadian journal Crux Mathematicorum (http://cms.math.ca/crux/). Though it is a problem solving journal, they do regularly publish short articles. With an audience primarily of undergraduate and secondary school students, (I suspect group theory is too advanced -- number theory is probably better received, or "pure" combinatorics), but others with similar questions might find them a better fit. Hope it helps.